# Expected singleton appears

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

If i select more than one employee this validation error appears

> Erreur lors de la validation de la contrainte
>
> Expected singleton: hr.employee(3, 5)

If I select just one employee I have the ability to create the record, and by modifying it I can select more

It seems like the validation exist just on the create function

```html
    employee_id0 = fields.Many2many('hr.employee', string='Employee', index=True)
department_id = fields.Many2many('hr.department', string="Department", store=True, required=True)
```

this is my view:

```html
 <field name="department_id" widget="many2many_checkboxes"/>
<field name="employee_id0"   widget="many2many_checkboxes"  />
```

Comment: Post your complete code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just trying to create multiple records in a single raw, that's why it throwing an error like: `Expected singleton: hr.employee(3, 5)`.
Make an iteration on that data and try to assign each record, like below example.

```
data = hr.employee(3,5)
for res in data:
    self.employee_id = res.id
```

Its just sample code.
Hope it will help you.